# How to get one record only once from a List?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Hi I have one list which is returning me multiple `employee name` , `number` with different `Trip`

> I want to show one employee name and employee number once only.
>
> how can i take a distinct `employee name`  and `employee number`

```
List<MYLIST> assm = Utilities.LoadEntityInstances<VMYLIST>()
// some code to get all data of MYLIST

List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
foreach (var item in assm)
{
    employees.Add(new Employee { Name = item.EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber = item.EmployeeNumber, LaborTypeName = item.LaborTypeName, SysId = item.Employee });
}
```

Nwow `employees` object returning me multiple records
I want to take only one record once `name` and `number`

Comment: Distinct by `EmployeeName` and `EmployeeNumber`, but you're also filling `LaborTypeName` and `SysID` properties. What with these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
employees.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.EmployeeNumber } )
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => 
    {
        var row = x.First();

        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\nNumber: {1}\nLabor: {2}\nSysId: {3}", x.Key.Name, x.Key.EmployeeNumber, row.LaborTypeName, row.SysId);  
    });
```

Or

```
var distincts = employees.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.EmployeeNumber } )
    .Select(x => new Employee  
    {
         Name = x.Key.Name,
         EmployeeNumber = x.Key.EmployeeNumber,
         LaborTypeName = x.First().LaborTypeName,
         SysId = x.First().SysId
    })
    .ToList();
```

But notice that it is a post factum actions. If you need to do it on the fly, then try this:

```
List<MYLIST> assm = Utilities.LoadEntityInstances<VMYLIST>()

List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
foreach (var item in assm)
{
    // if this element was not added before
    if (employees.All(x => x.Name != item.EmployeeName && x.EmployeeNumber != item.EmployeeNumber))
        employees.Add(new Employee { Name = item.EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber = item.EmployeeNumber, LaborTypeName = item.LaborTypeName, SysId = item.Employee });
}
```

This is a quite simple solution and not the most efficient actually. For increasing speed you can use `Dictionary`.

Comment: is this inside foreach ?

Comment: Thanks Should be in foreach ? syntax  ?
 foreach (var item in assignments){
var distincts = employees.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.EmployeeNumber } )
    .Select(x => new Employee  
    {
         Name = x.Key.Name,
         EmployeeNumber = x.Key.EmployeeNumber,
         LaborTypeName = x.First().LaborTypeName,
         SysId = x.First().SysId
    })
    .ToList();}

IS IT?

Comment: I see you need on the fly solutions? See my updated anser again :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var ls = employees.Select(x=>
    new {
        Name = x.EmployeeName
        ,Number = x.EmployeeNumber
    }
).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: is this inside foreach?

Comment: No. You will receive new List<dynamic>.